# Wifi signal goes low while connecting to my WiFi Hostspot?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, hotspot, signal-strength

I run a WiFi hotspot from my Windows 8.1 PC (Windows 10 Technical preview from last few days). When I try to connect from my android, the signal strength goes low and then results in authentication problem.

But after or before that, i.e. when the WiFi access point is only listed, it shows excellent signal strength.

Why does it happen so, or is there a remedy for that ?

---

<sub>OS: Windows Technical Preview x64

Drivers:

`Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter (HWID : PCI\VEN_14E4&DEV_4727&SUBSYS_1795103C&REV_01)`

         `Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller (HWID: PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8136&SUBSYS_1670103C&REV_05)`

*Don't know what/how to list [Please Check this result from Driver Identifier](http://www.driveridentifier.com/scan/desktop.php?scanid=0D60E9B0EAA64B3A956B8C727E102BB0)   
 
 
Hotspot created by [Virtual Router manager](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/)*

Client device: Micromax Canvas A1

Note: I previously used a Nokia 500 device which used to connect to my WiFi hotspot successfully. And as for my android, it can connect to other hotspots.</sub>

Comment: Please provide more information on your computer hardware and how you create the hotspot.

Comment: @harrymc check now

Comment: The question as always is whether the problem is with hardware or software. For testing hardware you will need another wifi adapter. For testing software, you can avoid using the Virtual Router manager and do this directly with Windows as [described here](http://winsupersite.com/article/faqtip/windows-7-tip-of-the-week-use-wireless-hosted-networking-to-share-an-internet-connection-wirelessly).

Comment: So when the authentication fails, does moving closer to the AP solve the problem?

Comment: @Jason how close? My laptop is on the table, and I am sitting by it on a chair !

Comment: I've seen this happen before. I'm not exactly sure this'll help, but you could disassemble your notebook and check whether the [U.FL connectors](http://www.tinkerforge.com/en/doc/_images/Extensions/extension_wifi_ufl_600.jpg) are [properly seated](http://cdn.overclock.net/8/83/500x1000px-LL-83b68e12_6230.jpeg) in the WiFi module.

Answer (score 0):

The transmit power of an AP changes based on its data rate.  In other words, lower data rates have a longer range.  I've noticed this behavior myself, and [I'm not the only one](http://www.quora.com/Why-does-wireless-signal-strength-often-decrease-upon-connecting-to-the-network).

It sounds like you're either on the fringe of your AP's range and/or your device is doing a poor job negotiating a connection speed.  For the former, move closer to the AP or use better or additional APs.  For the later, update the firmware of the APs and update the WLAN drivers for the devices.